# How to print 20 elements at a time in a for loop in python?

Tags: python

In my code below I can determine the prime number between a limit range from ri to rf and to print them the prime in each range in a separate line. But I can't find a way to print 20 prime numbers per line without using any arrays or list.

```
import math
# inc: increment of the range where the prime number are going to be determine
inc = 70
# ri: minimum variable range where the prime number are going to be determine
ri = 0
# ri: maximum variable range where the prime number are going to be determine
rf = inc
# rm: maximum range where the prime number are going to be determine
rm = 1000
# z: number of times the program is going to be repeated 
z = math.ceil(rm/inc)

for x in range(z):
    # iteration in the range ri<i<rf "0<i<20"
    for i in range(ri, rf):
        # determine if i is 0 or 1, since they are not prime
        if i > 1:
            # iteration in the range 2<j<i "2<j<3"
            for j in range(2, i):
                # determine if the number is not prime
                if (i % j) == 0:
                    # modulus of i%j " i% [2,3,4,5,....,i]"
                    break
                    # if it is prime break
            else:
                print(i, end=" ")
    # increment the evaluation range of the prime number
    ri += inc
    rf += inc
    # print new line
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Well, you've got `print(i, end=" ")`, so if that's being ran 20 times, it'll end up on one line. Maybe work on the logic of the break statement and your other print

Comment: add a counter, on each print of a prime increase it, if it hits 20, print a newline and reset counter to 0